# Redux persist v5 not working as it is supposed to

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I am making a react native application for which uses redux and redux-persist.

Actual behaviour: When a user logs in and closes the apen and reopens after some time he should directly go into logged in view. But in my application first the loggedout page comes up and after the store is rehydrated it automatically redirects to the loggedin view

App.js is as follows

```
 // all other import statements
 const { store } = configureStore({});

 class App extends Component {
   constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
    isReady: false,
  };
}

render() {
 const { isLoggedIn } = store.getState().auth;
 const Layout = CreateRootNavigator(isLoggedIn);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AlertProvider>
        <Root>
          <Layout />
       </Root>
      </AlertProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
 }
}
```

My createStore.js is as follows which uses redux-persist v5

```
function configureStore(initialState) {
  let store = createStore(
       persistedReducer,
       initialState,
      compose(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
    );

  let persistor = persistStore(store);
  // send this persistor also

  return { store };
}
```

The problem that I face is when I login and close the app and then reopen first theloggedout screen pops up and it automatically redirects to loggedin layout after the store is rehydrated. I probably want a flag or something after the store is rehydrated so that I can actually render the actual thing after store is rehydrated. Please help ... thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

It is clearly mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist), that you should use [`PersistGate`](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/PersistGate.md), to delay the rendering of your UI components.

> If you are using react, wrap your root component with PersistGate. This delays the rendering of your app's UI until your persisted state has been retrieved and saved to redux. **NOTE** the `PersistGate` loading prop can be null, or any react instance, e.g. `loading={<Loading />}`

Comment: My use case is different here... I am creating a layout using a flag in auth reducer.... even if I use a persistGate it doesnot work because persitGate just delays the rendering of the component (<Layout /> in my case).... I am sending an "isLoggedIn" to create that Layout which is at the beginning gives false and becomes true after the state has persisted..

Comment: `PersistGate` contains a prop`onBeforeLift`, on which you may perform your `layout` operation, before the `store is rehydrated`

Comment: doesn't help! same thing occurs login page pops up first and after about a second the loggedin view in rendered... onBeforeLift is called just before the store is rehydrated... I want to create the Layout only after the store is hydrated